# How can I Get AWS Cognito id token From Google Login?

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-play-services, amazon-cognito, aws-userpools

I looked it up for a month but couldn't find it. Unity and Google login links, Google and aws cognito links, and cognito and unity links exist, respectively, but I have not found a way to handle them at once.

I could follow [this Document](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ko_kr/cognito/latest/developerguide/google.html) and get AWS Credentials. However, it only provides access tokens for authorization, not ID token for authentication.

So, How can I Get AWS Cognito id token From Google Login?

I don't want to use the hosting UI provided by [this post](https://beabetterdev.com/2021/08/16/how-to-add-google-social-sign-on-to-your-amazon-cognito-user-pool/). I learned how to get an ID token from a post, but I want to know how to find it without opening an external browser in the app.

Comment: Did you find a solution already? Is there any? I have the same problem and I don't get any further...
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77579294/api-to-exchange-google-id-token-to-cognito-oauth-bearer-token

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom Auth token provider which is helpful to get cognito token for various federated service provider.

```js
import { Amplify } from 'aws-amplify';
import { TokenProvider, decodeJWT } from 'aws-amplify/auth';

const myTokenProvider: TokenProvider = {
  async getTokens({ forceRefresh } = {}) {
    if (forceRefresh) {
      // try to obtain new tokens if possible
    }

    const accessTokenString = '<insert JWT from provider>'; // google token
    const idTokenString = '<insert JWT from provider>'; // google token
    
    return {
      accessToken: decodeJWT(accessTokenString),
      idToken: decodeJWT(idTokenString),
    };
  },
};

Amplify.configure(awsconfig, {
  Auth: {
    tokenProvider: myTokenProvider
  }
});
```

Here is the link of documentation , visit it https://docs.amplify.aws/javascript/build-a-backend/auth/advanced-workflows/#custom-token-providers